# liquibase migration of mysql constraint - error on success op

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have the following changeset in migration:

```
<changeSet author="aaa (generated)" id="1416295794385-38" objectQuotingStrategy="QUOTE_ALL_OBJECTS">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="fk_xxx_id" baseTableName="client_xxxs" constraintName="FK_2kma3uvjxartf5p9l24yk2fxu" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false" onDelete="NO ACTION" onUpdate="NO ACTION" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="xxx_types"/>
</changeSet>
```

On exec of this I get an error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yyy_test`.`client_xxxs`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2kma3uvjxartf5p9l24yk2fxu` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_xxx_id`) REFERENCES `xxx_types` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

But when i check the schema in mysql, this constraint seems to be applied. This is the only time im applying the constraint and it has not been applied before.

```
show create table client_xxxs;
| client_xxxs | CREATE TABLE `client_xxxs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  `fk_xxx_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `xxx_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_2kma3uvjxartf5p9l24yk2fxu` (`fk_xxx_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2kma3uvjxartf5p9l24yk2fxu` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_xxx_id`) REFERENCES `xxx_types` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

This blocks migration from completing.

- What is the cause of this exception, is the a bug or any miss on the
  schema is triggering it?
- Any way to ignore errors and process with
  the remaining migrations?

Also verified that constraint application directly in mysql-console works fine.

```
mysql> alter table client_xxxs add  CONSTRAINT `x-FK_2kma3uvjxartf5p9l24yk2fxu` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_xxx_id`) REFERENCES `xxx_types` (`id`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.81 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

show create ...
CONSTRAINT `x-FK_2kma3uvjxartf5p9l24yk2fxu` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_xxx_id`) REFERENCES `xxx_types` (`id`),
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is being thrown by mysql when Liquibase tries to add the constraint. I think the error is due to data in the base column that doesn't match data in the referenced column. I would expect that the foreign key would not be created, but that may still be with mysql.

If you run `select * from client_xxxs where fk_xxx_id not in (select id from xxx_types)` do you get any results back?